# Install Ubuntu over Windows Vista or reformat the HDD and fresh install?

Tags: system-installation, cleanup

I'm considering changing from Windows Vista; I just need to know a few things first. I have a Toshiba P100 laptop with Vista preloaded. Unfortunately, it has become corrupted and no longer works. I am missing approximately 30GB of disk-space and now my machine is operating on somewhere between 64-69GB.  I assume that the rest of a 100GB HDD is taken up with Windows.

- I've done all that I can think of to recover as much as space as I could, so if I install Ubuntu what will I have to work with?
- Do I format the HDD and start from scratch or should I only install over Windows?

Comment: As an aside: If there is still data you need to get off Windows you can run Ubuntu from a CD and use it to pull the data from the HDD and move it to a USB stick. Then install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You have choices when you install, dual boot, wubi, or install into the entire hard drive. You can format the drive as a part of the installation.

I suggest you boot the live "cd" (from a flash drive), test your system, and if all looks good, start the installer.

On the partitioning section you can use the entire disk if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get to the installer you can chose if you want to install next to your operating system or over it entirely. There is also an option 'something else' but do not touch it if you are not sure what you are doing.If your vista is corrupted then I suggest installing over it. Your question is a little unclear btw. I am not sure what you are asking for.

Here is the download page for ubuntu btw:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to download Ubuntu from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (first try 64-Bit, if there should be any errors, retry with 32 bit) and then follow the following instructions to install Ubuntu:

[How to install Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)

Other than in the pictures there, I would choose "Replace Windows Vista with Ubuntu". 
But remark: This will delete all your files you have on your PC. Take a back up, if you don't know how:

1. Download Ubuntu from the link above
2. Burn it to a dvd
3. restart your computer, but boot from the dvd, usually you have to press F12 during the first seconds of the boot process to select the device
4. Wait, and select then try ubuntu.
5. Open "Files" and copy all your files to an external hard drive, a usb stick or a cloud.